# Bare metal STM32F vector table - how to setup the files & structures

Tags: vector, stm32, interrupt

I'm doing a bare metal STM32F bootloader and am struggling with getting the mechanics of declaring and linking the vector table.  I understand what goes into the table but don't understand how to implement it.

The example I'm working with has a two part implementation.  The actual table is defined in a .C file and the linker references the table.

Here's the code snippets:

```
// link.c
#define STACK_TOP ((void*)(0x20004000))

void isr_reset(void)
{
...
}

static const void *attr_sect("isrv_sys") _isrv_sys[] = {
    /* Cortex-M0 system interrupts */
    STACK_TOP,  /* Stack top */
    isr_reset,  /* Reset */
    isr_nmi,    /* NMI */
        .
        .
        .
};
```

```
// link.ld
SECTIONS
{
    .text 0x08000000: {
        *(isrv_sys); /* Interrupt Service Routine Vector (exceptions & IRQs) */
        . = 0x00000400;
        *(.text.romboot)
        *(.text)
    }
```

The result is the STACK_TOP gets put into the correct location but all the ISR pointers are zero.

I've managed to confuse myself after trying a LOT of things I've googled so now it's time to ask for help.

I'm using a WIN11 PC with the arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.

Comment: Your function pointers look fine, except you can't declare the vector static, it will get eliminated.  You need to make it extern to stop the compiler from removing it and you need KEEP() in your linker script to stop the linker from doing so.  See the cube package for examples.

Comment: The vector table isn't being eliminated.  I can see the STACK_TOP in the ELF disassembly and in the correct location in FLASH.  If I add a second STACK_TOP further down in the table, the second one also shows up in the proper places.  It's just the ISR pointers are all zero.  I added external statements for all the ISR routines but it didn't help.

Comment: Use `objdump -r` to view the relocations in the object file produced by the compiler without linking.  If there are relocations in each vector entry then the problem is at the linking stage, if there aren't then it is at the compiler.

Comment: They show up when I added the -r flag.  That lead me to finding the -r flag when the linker was called.  Deleting the -r linker flag got me a functional system.  Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your own answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to remove the -r flag from the linker options list.

Many thanks to Tom V for leading me down the path to success.